# Is multi robots simulation in kinetic possible?

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to do multi robot simulation like described in this answer in ROS kinetic? https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293568/is-multi-robots-simulation-in-kinetic-possible?/) by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2018-06-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it's possible to do multi-robot simulation with Kinetic as described in that answer. If you want anything beyond a "yes" you're going to have to update your question with more information such as what youre trying to do, what you've done, and what the results were.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-06-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [topkek](https://answers.ros.org/users/34642/topkek/) on 2018-06-08**:
so if its possible, here's my next question https://answers.ros.org/question/292571/problem-with-two-huskies-in-navigation/